# Elasticsearch - using mid-sentence words for completion suggester

Tags: elasticsearch

I have assembled an Elasticsearch index of search term suggestions that are used to feed a text input on the frontend that, as you type, shows a list of suggestions based on what you've typed so far. I'm using Elasticsearch 6.5.4. Following the docs, the index is set up with the following mapping:

```
PUT localhost:9200/search-suggestions

{
    "mappings": {
        "suggestion": {
            "properties": {
                "suggest": {
                    "type": "completion"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Suggestion terms are added like so:

```
POST localhost:9200/search-suggestions/suggestion

{
    "suggest": [ "News at six" ]
}
```

And a suggestion search is performed like so:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/search-suggestions/_search

{
    "suggest": {
        "autocomplete": {
            "text": "six",
            "completion": {
                "field": "suggest",
                "fuzzy": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The search term above is 'six', which returns no results (assuming the only document is the one from earlier, 'News at six'). If the search term is 'news', then the 'News at six' result is returned. This is as expected for the basic completion suggester.

Is there any way to produce the search result using any other word from the sentence - i.e. if I were to search 'at' or 'six' or 'at six'? I am not able to upgrade the version of Elasticsearch, and this is my first real foray into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using this article](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-implement-autocomplete-with-edge-n-grams-in-elasticsearch) I have gotten just what I need.

Instead of using a completion suggester, it uses an edge nGram query-based solution. Here is the setting/mapping for the index:

```
PUT localhost:9200/search-suggestions

{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 5
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "suggestions": {
            "properties": {
                "suggest": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add your docs as normal:

```
POST localhost:9200/search-suggestions/suggestions

{
    "suggest": [ "News at six" ]
}
```

And use match query to get appropriate suggestions:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/search-suggestions/suggestions/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "suggest": {
                "query": "at six",
                "analyzer": "standard",
                "fuzziness": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the text 'at six' will return a result for 'news at six'.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `completion` field, you can add another `text` sub-field on which you'll be able to run normal match queries.

```
PUT search-suggestions
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "suggest": {
        "type": "completion",
        "fields": {
          "text": {
            "type": "text"        <--- add this sub-field
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in addition to the suggest query, you can definitely add a normal search query on the `suggest.text` field that will match on any indexed token:

```
POST search-suggestions/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "suggest.text": "six"
    }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "text": "six",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "fuzzy": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will produce one hit from the query (match on `six`) and no suggestions.

The next query, however, will produce one hit (match on `news`) and one suggestion (starts with `news`)

```
POST search-suggestions/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "suggest.text": "news"
    }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "text": "news",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "fuzzy": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue adding a document to an index with that mapping - is this correct (had to add `_doc` to the mapping): `POST search-suggestions/_doc  { "suggest": { "input": ["news at six"], "text": "news at six" }}`

Comment: What error do you get? Which version are you running on?

Comment: Apologies for the late response - I've found the answer I was looking for and answered it here. I can't recall the error any more as it was a while ago, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign multiple words to the field 'suggest' like ['news at six', 'six'] at the time of indexing of the document.

```
PUT search-suggestions/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "suggest" : {
    "input": [ "News at six", "six" ]
  }
}
```